# Different Nagios email notifications for different services

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to send out a different style of notification for a specific service in Nagios, namely, when a user account gets locked out from AD.  I don't need all the excess information associated with the usual emails (e.g. Host the service pertains to, IP address, service status, etc), as all the information I need is given in the SNMP trap sent from Windows in `$SERVICEOUTPUT`.  However, I can't just change the notify-service-by-email command because I need to use the full output for all the other services.

I need to find a way to either:

1. Send out an email notification customized to this service

   ```
   define command{
           command_name    notify-service-by-email
           command_line    $~LongOutputCommand~$
   }

   define command{
           command_name    notify-lockouts-by-email
           command_line    $-ShortOutputCommand~$
   }

   define service{
           service_description        Account Lockouts
           service_notification       notify-lockouts-by-email
           ...
   }
   ```
2. Execute an if statement inside the command_line section of the Nagios command:

   ```
   define command{
           command_name    notify-service-by-email
           command_line    if [ "$SERVICEDESC" == "Account Lockouts" ]; then $-ShortOutputCommand~$; else $~LongOutputCommand~$; fi
   }
   ```

I don't believe it's possible for Nagios to do the first way because of the way it is programmed, but no matter how I try the second way it doesn't process it as a proper command ("if not recognized", etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a "script" syntax on a command_line definition. Think the command_line as an handler to call a script in action: the logic, and a if statement is "logic", must be moved in the script you are calling. Inside the script just use the if statement on $1 (the positional variable for the first argument passed to the script) and then process the value of $1. So, if $1 (in our case if you pass $SERVICEDESC is to the script as first argument, inside the script it is referenced as $1) equal to...